iOS Orphaned Words issue
I have expandable label. When I tapped to "daha fazla" label, I show to full text in label. Normally it works well but in this case it doesn't work. When I show to attributed string in label, it shows 3rd and last lane different than CTFrame.
This is how text looks in my label.

Here is my ctFrame log. When I logged, 3rd and last lane it looks different than label.

Here is my calculating code.
func characterIndex(at touchPoint: CGPoint) -> Int {

    guard let attributedString = attributedText, bounds.contains(touchPoint) else {
        return NSNotFound
    }

    let textRect = self.textRect(forBounds: bounds, limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines)
    
    if !textRect.contains(touchPoint) {
        return NSNotFound
    }

    // Offset tap coordinates by textRect origin to make them relative to the origin of frame
    // Convert tap coordinates (start at top left) to CT coordinates (start at bottom left)
    let point = CGPoint(x: touchPoint.x - textRect.origin.x,
                        y: textRect.size.height - (touchPoint.y - textRect.origin.y))
    
    let framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attributedString)
    let suggestedSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter,
                                                                     CFRangeMake(0, attributedString.length),
                                                                     nil,
                                                                     CGSize(width: textRect.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                                                     nil)

    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: suggestedSize.width, height: CGFloat(ceilf(Float(suggestedSize.height)))))

    let ctFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRange(), path, nil)
    let frameLines = CTFrameGetLines(ctFrame)
    let linesCount = numberOfLines > 0 ? min(numberOfLines, CFArrayGetCount(frameLines)) : CFArrayGetCount(frameLines)

    if linesCount.cgFloatValue.isZero {
        return NSNotFound
    }

    var lineOrigins = [CGPoint](repeating: .zero, count: linesCount)
    CTFrameGetLineOrigins(ctFrame, CFRangeMake(0, linesCount), &lineOrigins)

    for (idx, lineOrigin) in lineOrigins.enumerated() {
        var newLineOrigin = lineOrigin
        let lineIndex = CFIndex(idx)
        let line = unsafeBitCast(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(frameLines, lineIndex), to: CTLine.self)

        // Get bounding information of line
        var ascent: CGFloat = 0.0
        var descent: CGFloat = 0.0
        var leading: CGFloat = 0.0
        let width = CGFloat(CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, &ascent, &descent, &leading))
        let yMin = CGFloat(floor(lineOrigin.y - descent))
        let yMax = CGFloat(ceil(lineOrigin.y + ascent))

        // Apply penOffset using flushFactor for horizontal alignment to set lineOrigin since this is the horizontal offset from drawFramesetter
        let flushFactor = flushFactorForTextAlignment(textAlignment: textAlignment)
        let penOffset = CGFloat(CTLineGetPenOffsetForFlush(line, flushFactor, Double(textRect.size.width)))
        newLineOrigin.x = penOffset

        // Check if we've already passed the line
        if point.y > yMax {
            return NSNotFound
        }

        // Check if the point is within this line vertically
        if point.y >= yMin && point.x >= lineOrigin.x && point.x <= lineOrigin.x + width {
            // Convert CT coordinates to line-relative coordinates
            let relativePoint = CGPoint(x: point.x - lineOrigin.x, y: point.y - lineOrigin.y)
            return Int(CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition(line, relativePoint))
        }
    }

    return NSNotFound
}

